How do I use page.id in a Jekyll / Liquid for loop?
Each page has an id in frontmatter:
---
title: How it Works
layout: page
id: howitworks
---
...

I have a _config.yml file:
progressbar:
  index:
    - "firstIndex"
    - "secondIndex"
    - "thirdIndex"
  howitworks:
    - first
    - second
    - third

I want to create an include which loops through progressbar and grabs each item from site.progressbar.{{page.id }}
For example:
<ul>
  {% for thing in site.progressbar.{{ page.id }} %}
    <li>{{ thing }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

Is this possible?
ps. I can change anything about the way this is done, including how _config.yml is defined if it makes things easier.
Assuming I'm on page howitworks I should see:
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
</ul>


I propose two solutions:
Option 1 - using _config.yml
Keeping the _config.yml as described in the question, this code should work:
<!-- _includes/my-include-configyaml.html -->
{% assign progressbar_configyaml = site.progressbar[include.id]%}
<ul>
  {% for thing in progressbar_configyaml %}
    <li>{{ thing }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<!-- example_page.html -->
---
title: How it Works
layout: page
id: howitworks
---

{% include my-include-configyaml.html id=page.id %}


Option 2 - using a data file
Alternatively, the data could be instead stored at _data/my-config-data.json.
[
    {
        "progressbar": {
            "index": [
                "firstIndex",
                "secondIndex",
                "thirdIndex"
            ],
            "howitworks": [
                "first",
                "second",
                "third"
            ]
        }
    }
]

Then the code will be:
<!-- _includes/my-include-datafile.html -->
{% assign progressbar_datafiles = site.data.my-config-data[0].progressbar[include.id] %}

<ul>
  {% for thing in progressbar_datafiles %}
    <li>{{ thing }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<!-- example_page.html -->
---
title: How it Works
layout: page
id: howitworks
---

{% include my-include-datafile.html id=page.id %}



